# Why there isn't an <input type="picture"> and/or <input type="video"> in HTML5?

Tags: html, mobile, camera

I guess this is a retorical question but I would like to hear what others think about this.

The simplest use case in the world would be to access a mobile web site from my phone and post a picture that I will just take (or even one from my camera roll). Nowadays I simply can't do that. Many clients would think that this a "natural" feature, and is hard to tell them that you simply can't do that. You need the either build an app for such a simple task, or have to use some kind of special browser app that hacks into file inputs to allows you to choose a picture, which clearly is not something they would like their final user have to do.

Input type video I guess it would be a little bit harder, but doesn't hurt to dream....

Comment: They are actually working on this: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/getusermedia-access-camera-privacy-ui/

Comment: Agree with laurens, and the current name is getusermedia which was known as <html5 device>
You still can do it with C++/Ajax or flash but yeah getUserMedia will be a dream come true.

Comment: getUserMedia seems to be for streaming. I'm looking for a simple "form post based" solution... just submit a picture the way you submit your name, your address and your email.... But agree that is a great API too, really no more flash!.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with HTML5, and HTML4.01.  Use `<input type="file" accept="image/*"/>` for pictures and `<input type="file" accept="video/*"/>` for videos.

As far as I know, Internet Explorer and Safari will not even attempt to restrict based on this, but you need server-side MIME validation anyway.

Comment: You are missing the point. The idea is to allow a mobile web site to receive pictures and/or videos from the users phone; don't care about restricting types, just allow users to upload pictures without having to develop a custom app for it. Just starting on iOS 6, Safari allows you to fill an <input type="file"/> with a picture form your camera roll. And I believe that Android is doing it since 2.3

Comment: The code above works on mobile devices. According to [this 2013 O'Reilley book](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=gswdarRZVUoC&pg=PA263&dq=%22file+upload+compatibility+table%22) support for `<input type="file"/>` started with Safari on iOS6 and Android 2.2

Answer (score 1):

According to this webpage: http://www.w3.org/2009/dap/ the feature will be available through the javascript Device API (HTML Media Capture). But no actual implementations has been confirmed yet.

But we are many who look forward to when it does :)

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-media-capture-20110414/ actually does exactly what I want... wonder why is taking so long to finish the spec and to actually implement it on webkit!

Comment: Beats me. This will be so nice. All HTML 5 need is more intercativity with the mobile device, to be truly awsome and to be a serious alternative to native apps :)

Answer (score 0):

`<Input type="picture">` or `<input type="video">` is **not** possible in HTML5. But you can add `<input type="file">` and validate it with JavaScript or HTML itself according to its extension you may can see http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/type if anything went wrong comment me. There is `<input type=image src=you.jpg>` is used to create a image-submit button

Comment: And what would be the benefit of putting such a tag that does nothing?? I'm asking basically to be able to post a picture thru a form in a mobile phone... not to be able to make my own HTML syntax